# Is there a difference between regular Mysql and MariaDB with Curdate which is messing up my query?

Tags: mysqli

In `MYSQL` this command used to find all dates before now. `< CURDATE()` but it stopped working.

For several years I used a select statement to find not completed hotel bookings in the past so I could delete them.  Then about 6 months ago my `php` script started deleting important bookings in the future. There must be some subtle difference in the way that `MYSQL` is processing my query.

In my database a booking has an arrival day, the length of say is duration.
(so the leaving date is arrival date plus duration)

It is supposed to find bookings where the leaving date was more than 3 days ago.  But it is finding bookings in the future too.

```
DELETE FROM booking WHERE status_id = 1 AND date_add(booking.arrivalday, INTERVAL duration DAY)+3 < CURDATE()
```

This code worked fine until a few months ago. Did `MYSQL` make some change that made it stop working.

I have just logged into the database to see which version of mysql I am using.

I was surprised to learn that it is

```
MySQL version: 10.1.37-MariaDB-cll-lve through PHP extension MySQLi
```

I am using A1 hosting. 
I thought I was using regular `MYSQL` not `maria MYSQL`.

I am now starting to suspect that the problem with my query is caused by a difference between regular `MYSQL` and `maria MYSQL`.

Can anyone shed any light on this ????

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution which is the following.

```
DELETE FROM booking WHERE status_id = 1 AND date_add(booking.arrivalday, INTERVAL duration DAY) < (CURDATE() -3)
```

A tiny change of syntax makes the query work. 
What caused it to stop working remains a mystery.
The only thing that I can think of is changing from regular PHP to Maria PHP.

Comment: I think that the proper syntax is `date_add(booking.arrivalday, INTERVAL 3 + duration DAY) < CURDATE()`

Comment: The hosting company just confirmed that the database was changed to Maria db in June 2018. They did not tell me.  That caused me a lot of embarrassment and a lot of inconvenience to a lot of people. Several double bookings were made . I had to lock down my entire database using a trigger to prevent any deletions. So there are  can be very serious implications from changing from normal MYSQL to Maria DB

Comment: I believe that you are not entirely right. The hosting company obviously is guilty for not informing you about the change ahead of time. But also, your old code is not fully SQL compliant - even though MySQL forgives you when you add INTEGER and DATE types, the right thing to do is to use DATE_ADD() and DATE_SUB() functions for such operations and to not rely on some side effects. Such side effects will break your code as you have seen.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have changed to my  query to the one you suggested. I don't know enough about MYSQL to know what  "side effects" are.  Is there a good online mysql syntax checker you know of. This one said my old code was OK. https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Comment: According to the manual (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/type-conversion/#rules-for-conversion-on-dyadic-arithmetic-operations) you should not rely on implicit type casting - like adding INTEGER to a DATE. Even if the syntax is okay, the implicit casting can play a joke with you.